# How to fadeIn and fadeOut in sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fadein, fadeout

I want `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` effect on div one by one sequentially with regular interval. I tried with following code but it will all div at a time `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`.

**HTML**

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
function fade()
{
   $("div").each(function(){
       $(this).fadeOut(3000);
   });
   $("div").each(function(){
       $(this).fadeIn(3000);
   });
}
setInterval(fade,6000);
```

**Update**

> I want First of all div one by one disappear from screen. When all div disappear then one by one show. This should happen regular interval.

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1n30hp49/2/)**

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/sofl/1n30hp49/9/

Comment: Or this? http://jsfiddle.net/philip100/1n30hp49/11/ :-)

Comment: No, In your code div position changed. It should not happen. First one by one all div disappear and then one by one appear on screen.

Comment: or this http://jsfiddle.net/gvecqxjd/embedded/result/

Comment: I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Moonbird_IT/1n30hp49/13/ . You may execute a function as soon as transition has been completed inside the fadeOut/fadeIn function.

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/om4b7ch1/1/

Comment: I reach nearest my solution but not 100% success. I want something like http://jsfiddle.net/1n30hp49/14/

Comment: According to "No, In your code div position changed", I changed the fadeIn/fadeOut to fadeTo (opacity is changed instead of display) http://jsfiddle.net/sofl/1n30hp49/15/

Comment: @sofl Thanks Exactly what I want. Give solution as answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to execute deferred actions sequentially. Here is a good article about this http://www.paulirish.com/2008/sequentially-chain-your-callbacks-in-jquery-two-ways/

According to the comments and your later defined needs, you can solve it like this and use fadeTo instead of fadeIn/fadeOut

```
var start = $('div:first');

function fade(lobj){
    lobj.fadeTo('slow',lobj.css('opacity')==1 ? 0 : 1,function(){
        var nobj = lobj.next();
        if(nobj.length)
            fade(nobj);
        else
            fade(start);
    });
}

fade(start);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sofl/1n30hp49/15/

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use the function **next** on jQuery, like this, I just wrote forking in your snippet on jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/1n30hp49/17/

In this code above I also used the $el to define who is going to be the next element:

```
function fade( el, timer ){
el.fadeOut( timer , function() {
    $( this ).fadeIn( timer , function() {
        fade( $( this ).next(), timer ) ;
    } ) ;
} ) ;
}

var timer = 1000 ;

//run function
fade( $( "div:first-child" ), 1000 ) ;
```

try to do this, if so, let me know if it works! att.

Answer (score 0):

A reliable way to do this would be to use jQuery animation queues and a deferred object in a recursive loop. The advantage of this method is the ease you can add animations into the fade function. It is also much easier to read than a bunch of nested callbacks.

```
// Get all the div elements
var divs = $('div');

/**
 * Fade in a specific indexed div element
 * @param {integer} i
 * @return {object} $.promise
 */
function fade(i)
{
    return divs.eq(i)
        .fadeIn(3000)
        .delay(6000)
        .fadeOut(3000)
        .promise();
}

/**
 * Recursive sequence runner
 * @param {integer} i
 */
function runSequence(i) {
    // If i is null/false set it to 0
    i = ! i ? 0 : i;

    // Run animation on item i
    var promise = fade(i);

    // Use the promise to queue up the next item
    // by calling this function again when the
    // animation is complete
    promise.then(function() {
        if (i > divs.length) {
            i = 0;
        }

        runSequence(++i);
    });
}

// Run the sequence for the first time
runSequence();
```

[**JSFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/1n30hp49/2/)

Answer (score 0):

There's been some great answers here but just to add to the diversity, here's another way with just good-ol' Fade in's and outs:

#### PLEASE NOTE

Stackoverflow's method of including third party scripts in their snippets interferes with this example so I had to add a container div around the other divs. For a purer example see the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/257z0n0f/)**.

```js
function fade() {
    
    var thisObj = this;
 
    thisObj.out = function(el, timer) {
     
        el.fadeOut( timer , function() {
            
            if ($( this ).prev().length > 0) {
            
                thisObj.out( $( this ).prev(), timer );
                
            } else {
                thisObj.in( $( "#container").find("div:first-child" ), timer );
            }
        } ) ;        
    }  
    thisObj.in = function(el, timer) {
     
        el.fadeIn( timer , function() {
            
            if ($( this ).next().length > 0) {
                
                thisObj.in( $( this ).next(), timer ) ;
                
            } else {
                thisObj.out( $( "#container").find("div:last-child" ), timer );
            }
            
        } );       
    }     
    
}

new fade().out( $( "#container").find("div:last-child" ), 1000 );
```

```css
#container div {
    background : #00f;
    height: 50px;
    width : 50px;
    margin : 5px;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

To change the order of the fade in and out, just change `last-child` to `first-child`.